# How to return more than one string?

Tags: swift

I am having a problem with returning more than two strings at time, as you can see by my code below I can only return to strings at a time, How do I return more than two to the page? Do I need to add another colon?

```
 func bmoViewPagerDataSourceNaviagtionBarItemTitle(_ viewPager: BmoViewPager, navigationBar: BmoViewPagerNavigationBar, forPageListAt page: Int) -> String? {


        return page == 0 ? "My Recipes" : "Catagories"

    }
```

Comment: What are you trying too achieve? Right now you return my recipes for the page 0 and categories otherwise. You could put another condition instead of categories.

Comment: Storing multiple things together as one thing is the purpose of collections like `Array`. But without knowing what exactly you're trying to achieve, it's hard to prescribe any solutions

Comment: `return page == 0 ? "My Recipes" : page == 1 ? "Catagories" : nil`

Comment: or using an array `let titles = ["My Recipes", "Catagories", "Any Title"]` and then just `return titles[page]`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you so much for your comment this worked as well! If I could upvote this comment and have it as an answer I would! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @LeoDabus I didn't put that in my answer because what if there's an index out of bounds? If you were to write it up, might be good to put in the error-check.

Comment: @matt your answer is good enough for that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for a switch statement.

```
return page == 0 ? "My Recipes" : "Catagories"
```

...is the same as

```
var result : String?
switch page {
case 0 : result = "My Recipes"
default : result = "Catagories"
}
return result
```

So now it's easy for you to add `case 1:`, `case 2:`, and so on.

On the other hand, an array might be simpler, as has been suggested in the comments.